# How to alternately colour every other merged-row in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet full of merged cells in column A.

A1:A2 is merged, A3:A4 is merged, A5:A6 is merged, A7:A8 is merged, etc.

B1:B8 are *not* merged.

I'd like to apply highlighting to every other group of rows, to make them visually more distinct.

So rows 1 & 2 should be white, 3 & 4 blue, 5 & 6 white, 7 & 8 blue, etc.

Each group in this case is 2 cells high, but that's not always the case.  I'm after a generic solution, ideally.

I tried using a table but they don't seem to be compatible with merged cells.

I tried writing some simple VBA, but was getting nowhere - `Mycell.MergeArea.Rows.Count` kept on returning 1 when it should have been 2?

Some pointers would be fantastic, thank you!

Comment: You'll need a conditional format.  What have you tried?

Comment: In conditional formats?  Nothing, I had no idea it was possible to do this sort of thing with CF.  I'm looking now, but I can't see anything relevant - can you give me a clue?

Comment: You want to base your condition on the row of each cell (`ROW()`) something like `=OR(MOD(ROW(),4)=0,MOD(ROW()+1,4)=0)` should work

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I find the Conditional Formatting a bit hard to grasp. It's often messed up if there are new rows inserted inside a previously CF'd range.

I'd try something like this:

- Select range to be colored
- Loop through the range activating the cells. 
  Beware that using `For Each` won't distinguish between merged or
  single cells.
- Go to next cell (merged or single) by using `activecell.Offset(1,0).Activate`
- Use a loop index to find every other cell to be colored.